# Take existing value of transform: translateX option

Tags: css, less

Here is `<div>` with style:

```
<div style="transform: translateX(1565px) translateY(159px) translateZ(0px)">
</div>
```

I want to add **class** that can calculate existing value of **translateX** and subtract 140(for example) from it. Is it possible to do that?

Regards, Nick

Comment: can you elaborate more what you aim to achieve? don't simply describe what you think is needed to be done. Probably you are looking for a bad solution

Comment: You can save the `translateX` value in a variable, and use this variable in your CSS. Would this work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you would consider using css variables? With them you can define just the offset value in a class, and use that value inside the main class that calculates the actual translation. In the example below you can see that i defined small utility classes just modify the offset value.

```css
/* for visual purposes */
.box {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: grey;
margin: 10px;
}

.box{
  --offset: 0px;
  transform: translateX(calc(15px + var(--offset))) translateY(2px) translateZ(0px);
}

.smallOffset{
  --offset: 10px;
}

.bigOffset{
  --offset: 40px;
}

.negativeOffset{
  --offset: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box smallOffset"></div>

<div class="box bigOffset"></div>

<div class="box negativeOffset"></div>
```

Unfortunately, the support for css variables is [not perfect](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), as IE is not supported at all. For more details about usage of `--variable`, `var(--variable)` and related, please refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`calc()`](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/func_calc.asp)

```css
.decrease{
transform: translateX(calc(1565px - 140px)) translateY(159px) translateZ(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="decrease">
div
</div>
```

[**With media-query:**](https://jsfiddle.net/gm76kp9y/)

```css
.decrease{
    transform: translateX(1565px) translateY(159px) translateZ(0px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .decrease {
     transform: translateX(calc(1565px - 140px)) translateY(159px) translateZ(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="decrease">
    div
</div>
```

[**Using Less and parameter:**](https://codepen.io/leenmalka/pen/BvZLqG)

```
@translateX : 1565px;
.decrease{
    transform: translateX(@translateX) translateY(159px) translateZ(0px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .decrease {
     transform: translateX(calc(@translateX - 140px)) translateY(159px) translateZ(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: That would probably work, but I need to override that value. Because I have media queries that change value of translateX. There no one fixed 1565px value

Comment: where the value of `translateX` is? do you save it in parameter?